# Как записать данные в класс обращаясь к объекту не напрямую?

Tags: java, ооп

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Beacon beacon_1 = new Beacon();
        beacon_1.ID = "5Wld";  //initialize
        Beacon beacon_2 = new Beacon();
        beacon_2.ID = "Cb8R";  //initialize
        Beacon beacon_3 = new Beacon();
        beacon_3.ID = "PfhR";  //initialize
        Beacon beacon_4 = new Beacon();
        beacon_4.ID = "Y9gz";  //initialize
        Beacon beacon_5 = new Beacon();
        beacon_5.ID = "Q15V";  //initialize
        Object[] beacons = new Object[] {
                beacon_1, beacon_2, beacon_3, beacon_4, beacon_5
        };  //initialize
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  //initialize
        String[] Active_beacon_list = new String[] {"5Wld", "PfhR", "Y9gz", "Q15V"};

        for (int i = 0; i > Active_beacon_list.length; i++) {
            String ID = scanner.nextLine();  // получение данных от маяков
            int RSSI  = scanner.nextInt();   // получение данных от маяков
            for (int a = 0; a > Active_beacon_list.length; a++) {
                if (ID == Active_beacon_list[a])
                    beacons[a].Last_rssi = RSSI;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Мне приходят данные от маяков ID и Rssi(сила сигнала), по ID я могу понять координату маяка, по Rssi расстояние до него. Я решил создать класс beacon в котором они будут хранится ID, Rssi и массив с последними 5 Rssi для рассчёта дистанции по формуле, как мне вызывать beacon_5.last_rssi при этом указывая не beacon_5, а брать из массива маяков beacons?

Comment: У вас проблема в том, что не компилируется эта строка `beacons[a].Last_rssi = RSSI;` ? Коли так, то просто объявите массив так: `Beacon [] beacons = new Beacon[]{...}`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Ели у вас проблема в том, что не компилируется эта строка

```
beacons[a].Last_rssi = RSSI;
```

то просто объявите массив так:

```
Beacon [] beacons = new Beacon[]{...}
```